# How do I combine these two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two arrays:
Page Views

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 15
    "views" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "teaser"
    "hour" => 15
    "views" => 2
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 17
    "views" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "teaser"
    "hour" => 17
    "views" => 3
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 21
    "views" => 1
  ]
]
```

Button Clicks

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 15
    "clicks" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "teaser"
    "hour" => 15
    "clicks" => 3
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "teaser"
    "hour" => 17
    "clicks" => 1
  ]
]
```

I'd like to get this:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 15
    "views" => 1
    "clicks" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "teaser"
    "hour" => 15
    "views" => 2
    "clicks" => 3
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 17
    "views" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "teaser"
    "hour" => 17
    "views" => 3
    "clicks" => 1
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "lp_group" => "store"
    "hour" => 21
    "views" => 1
  ]
]
```

In case you don't see it, one of the arrays (for each hour/lp_group) counts `views` the other `clicks`. I'd like to render these in a table, so I need to "combine" them into one array.

Neither `array_merge` nor `array_merge_recursive` work properly. And all the others I've tried overwrite data.

Comment: When asking question related to arrays it is more helpful for us if you provide the output of `var_export()`

Comment: There's no built-in function that does this. Loop through the clicks array, and for each element find the corresponding array of page views and add the `clicks` element.

Comment: Why doesn't `$result = array_merge_recursive($ary1, $ary2);` work properly?

Comment: @AlexBarker it combines the two arrays into one 8 element array.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I have been fighting with it for a while, didn't realize these types of questions aren't right. Shan't do it again.

Comment: The first two elements of the two arrays match, the other elements don't have any corresponding elements in the two arrays. Are the matching elements always in the same indexes?

Comment: Why does one of the elements in the results have an empty `clicks` value, but the other elements that aren't in the clicks array omit this column entirely.

Comment: Do you have control over the source arrays? You could make your life a lot easier simply by using the `lp_group` as array keys.

Comment: Never mind. There's no logical association between the two arrays you are trying to merge, tbh. What is the connection between array element 0 in array 1 with array element 0 in array 2?

Comment: @Barmar typo, sorry. Updated

Comment: Where does `clicks => 1` come from in element 3 of the result? It doesn't seem to match any of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Define your two arrays as $ar1 and $ar2 and try code below:

```
$ar = array_map(function ($ar1, $ar2){
        if ($ar1['lp_group'] == $ar2['lp_group'] && $ar1['hour'] == $ar2['hour']) {
            $ar1['clicks'] = $ar2['clicks'];
        }
        return $ar1;
    }, $ar1, $ar2);
```

Comment: This won't work. The two arrays are different lengths, and the elements don't correspond directly. You need to search for the matching `lp_group` and `hour`.

Comment: Here is the code. Try it, it works
https://codeshare.io/jGzQ9

Comment: What is this doing: `array_shift(array_diff($ar2, $ar1)`? Why not just `$ar2['clicks']`?

Comment: I see, the two arrays do seem to be in the same order.

Comment: Actually, only the first two elements match up. The rest don't have any correspondence.

Comment: You're right. Shift and diff is like over-engineering it. I'll update it.

Comment: I suspect the correspondence between the first two elements of the arrays is a coincidence, but I've asked for clarification in a comment above.

Comment: I assume it's just a part of a bigger thing. He needed merging only where it's adding up.